# Linq2Twitter Bad Authentication Data Error 215

Tags: twitter

I'm getting a LinqToTwitter.TwitterQueryException "Bad Authentication Data" with innerException "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

I'm using the latest version of LinqToTwitter (v2.1.06) and Twitter API v1.1.

The following code is used for authentication:

```
private XAuthAuthorizer GetAuthorizer()
        {
            var auth = new XAuthAuthorizer
            {
                Credentials = new XAuthCredentials
                {
                    ConsumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY,
                    ConsumerSecret = CONSUMER_SECRET,
                }
            };

            auth.Credentials.AccessToken = ACCESS_TOKEN;
            auth.Credentials.OAuthToken = OAUTH_TOKEN;
            auth.Authorize();
            return auth;
        }
```

And the error happens on the line of the foreach loop below:

```
XAuthAuthorizer _auth = GetAuthorizer();
   _twitter = new TwitterContext(_auth);
var friendTweets = from tweet in _twitter.Status where tweet.Type == StatusType.Show && tweet.ID == tweetID select tweet;

                    foreach (var tweet in friendTweets)
                    {
                        AddTweetToCache(tweetID, tweet);
                        return tweet;
                    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it. I was using the authentication method.

```
var auth = new ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer 
                { 
                    Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials 
                { 
                    ConsumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY, 
                    ConsumerSecret = CONSUMER_SECRET 
                } 
                };
```